# Overlapped tiles for custom image map type in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am implementing a prototype of an online game, whose map tiles are hexagons. I have the PNG files of tiles (which are rectangles of course), can I allow overlap in Google Map so that the tiles can be placed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by the API.

By that I mean that tiles aren't overlapped. You can however approach the problem from a different angle (1 maps api tile != 1 game tile).